# Android Manifest xml not recognizing name attribute for tags

Tags: xml, android-manifest, aapt

How-dy Folks!

I'm new to android and all, I have a problem with configuring the Android manifest for an app.
it seems like other than the "name" attribute, everything else written in the manifest file is recognized. can you please help me understand what I did wrong?
This is the xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http//schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.Axt_Software.MainPackage"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="2"/>
    <application android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_la">
        <activity name="com.Axt_Software.MainPackage.TestApp"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

This is the command that I use to make R.class for my program:

> aapt package -v -f -m -S res -J src -M AndroidManifest.xml -I C:\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar

Also this is the error I get when I run the command on my cmd:

> AndroidManifest.xml:6: Tag  missing required attribute name.
>
> AndroidManifest.xml:7: Tag  missing required attribute name.
>
> AndroidManifest.xml:8: Tag  missing required attribute name.
>
> AndroidManifest.xml:12: Tag  missing required attribute name.
>
> AndroidManifest.xml:15: Tag  missing required attribute name.
>
> AndroidManifest.xml:16: Tag  missing required attribute name.

Also, if I remove all the tags who need the name attribute, I get a R.class of only raw resources.

thanks a lot